# Counting if part of string is within interval

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to check if a number in a comma-separated string is within a number interval. What I am trying to do is to check if an area code (from the comma-separated string) is within the interval of an area.

### The data:
AREAS

| Area interval | Name | Number of locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000-1499 | Area 1 | ? |
| 1500-1799 | Area 2 | ? |
| 1800-1999 | Area 3 | ? |

### GEOLOCATIONS

| Name | Areas List |
| --- | --- |
| Location A | 1200, 1400 |
| Location B | 1020, 1720 |
| Location C | 1700, 1920 |
| Location D | 1940, 1950, 1730 |

The result I want here is the number of unique locations in the "Areas list" within the area interval. So Location D should only count ONCE in the 1800-1999 "area", and the Location A the same in the 1000-1499 location. But location B should count as one in both 1000-1499 and one in 1500-1799 (because a number from each interval is in the comma-separated string in "Areas list"):

| Area interval | Name | Number of locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000-1499 | Area 1 | 2 |
| 1500-1799 | Area 2 | 3 |
| 1800-1999 | Area 3 | 2 |

How is this possible?

I have tried with a COUNTIFS, but it doesnt seem to do the job.

Comment: Can 'Area List' contain concatenated string longer than just two areas?

Comment: @JvdV Yes it could be 100+ in a comma separated list. :)

Comment: Is 1800-1999 really Area 3 in the tables above?

Comment: @TomSharpe Yeah of course - that was a mistake from my side. Sorry! I have made an edit accordingly :)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you have 3 locations in area 2. There are only two numbers that are in the range 1500-1799 which are 1720 and 1700, meaning locations B and C, just two unique locations.....right?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @JvdV You are absolutely right, that was a mistake in the data. Now I have changed it. I have 1730 in Location D, which is why I expect 3. :)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I am using latest version from Microsoft Office 365. I am not exactly sure which version that is. :)

Comment: Sorry, yet another question - is the data currently in tables or just in columns?

Comment: @TomSharpe I think it is just in columns - so "pure" vanilla Excel setup, but I can change it if necessary. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one option using `FILTERXML()`:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<x><t>"&TEXTJOIN("</s></t><t>",,"1<s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B$7:B$10,", ","</s><s>"))&"</s></t></x>","//t[count(.//*[.>="&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","][.<=")&"])>0]"))
```

Where:

- `"<x><t>"&TEXTJOIN("</s></t><t>",,"1<s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B$7:B$10,", ","</s><s>"))&"</s></t></x>"` - Is the part where we construct a valid piece of XML. The theory here is that we use three axes here. Each t-node will be named a literal `1` to make sure that once we return them with xpath we can sum the result. The outer x-nodes are there to make sure Excel will handle the inner axes correctly. If you are curious to know how this xml-syntax looks at the end, it's best to step through using the 'Evaluate Formula' function on the Data-tab;
- `//t[count(.//*[.>="&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","][.<=")&"])>0]"))` - Basically means that we collect all t-nodes where the count of child s-nodes that are >= to the leftmost number and <= to the rightmost number is larger than zero. For `A2` the xpath would look like `//t[count(.//*[.>=1000][.<=1499])>0]"))` after substitution. In short: `//t` - Select t-nodes, where `count(.//*` select all child-nodes where count of nodes that fullfill both requirements `[.>=1000][.<=1499]` is larger than zero;
- Since all t-nodes equal the number 1, the `SUM()` of these t-nodes equals the amount of unique locations that have at least one area in its Areas List;
- Important to note that `FILTERXML()` will result into an error if no t-nodes could be found. That would mean we need to wrap the `FILTERXML()` in an `IFERROR(...., 0)` to counter that and make the `SUM()` still work correctly.

---

Or, wrap the above in `BYROW()`:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(a,SUM(FILTERXML("<x><t>"&TEXTJOIN("</s></t><t>",,"1<s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B$7:B$10,", ","</s><s>"))&"</s></t></x>","//t[count(.//*[.>="&SUBSTITUTE(a,"-","][.<=")&"])>0]"))))
```

Comment: This is so complicated. Do you know a (video)Tutorial where the first solution is explained? Not even the filterxml function I understand the way you use it. It seems you have two containers inside.

Comment: @Prema, I don't know about a video, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) older post of mine would help you understand better. But yes, there are two axes here. One relation from parent `x` to child `t` which has it's own childnodes `s`. If it helps I could try to explain more in depth in the post itself?

Comment: @Prema, I edited the post to explain a little bit more.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the explanation. It is a lot to go thorough, but worth it, because it is so useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using MMULT and TEXTSPLIT:

```
=LET(rng,TEXTSPLIT(D2,"-"),
    tarr,IFERROR(--TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,$B$2:$B$5),",",";")),0),
    SUM(--(MMULT((tarr>=--TAKE(rng,,1))*(tarr<=--TAKE(rng,,-1)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(tarr),,1,0))>0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am in very distinguished company but will add my version anyway as byrow probably is a slightly different approach

```
=LET(range,B$2:B$5,
lowerLimit,--@TEXTSPLIT(E2,"-"),
upperLimit,--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(E2,"-"),2),
counts,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(r,SUM((--TEXTSPLIT(r,",")>=lowerLimit)*(--TEXTSPLIT(r,",")<=upperLimit)))),
SUM(--(counts>0))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here the ugly way to do it, with A LOT of helper columns. But not so complicated

```
F4= =TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<m><r>"&SUBSTITUTE(B4;",";"</r><r>")&"</r></m>";"//r"))
F11=    =TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<m><r>"&SUBSTITUTE(A11;"-";"</r><r>")&"</r></m>";"//r"))
F16=    =SUM(F18:F21)
F18=    =IF(SUM(($F4:$O4>=$F$11)*($F4:$O4<=$G$11))>0;1;"")
G18=    =IF(SUM(($F4:$O4>=$F$12)*($F4:$O4<=$G$12))>0;1;"")
H18=    =IF(SUM(($F4:$O4>=$F$13)*($F4:$O4<=$G$13))>0;1;"")
```

[image]